# Loop through Observable data, push to array, and display all results from array typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http, typescript

How do i loop through my data, that i subscribed to as an Observable, push it to an array, and displaying the whole data of the array?
My present code only displays data from each "page", and not all the pages. 
The reason why i want to do this, is because i want to make an infinity scroll.

Thank you!

Component:

```
  this.storiesService.getData(this.page, this.hits, this.feed)
  .subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (!data || data.hits === 0) {
      this.finished = true;
      console.log("NO MORE HITS")
    } else {
      this.finished = false;
      for (let story of data.hits) {
        this.hitsArray.push(story);
        console.log("Hit me!")
        console.log(this.hitsArray);
      }
    }
  })
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let story of hitsArray">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'image'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" />
    <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'video'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" width="150" height="94" />
    <div class="caption">
      <p>{{story.storyCity}}, {{story.storyCountry}}</p>
      <h3>{{story.storyHeadline}}</h3>
      <p>Uploadet {{story.uploadDate}}</p>
      <p>Bruger: {{story.userDisplayName}}</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Like</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you bring out just the specific part that is not working as it should instead of the whole code

Comment: @TheophilusOmoregbee Done. It's the part with the hitsArray, where i want to push the data from the observable, and then display all of the data, after i've put it in the array. Im using ngx-infinity-scroll to trigger and adjust the scrolling in the HTML part. The *ngFor part is the part that loops through the data and display every image of the iterable.

Comment: so you are trying to add the new page data to the previous ones(`hitsArray`) and then your `ngFor` can now display the newly added items, hope i got the problem statement right?

Comment: You got it exactly right. Sorry if i havent been fully explanatory, im still learning angular.

Comment: The answer I provided should fix it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your component's template, you are using `data` which is updated for every newly fetched data from observable here in your subscription

```
for (let story in data) {
        this.data = data; --> here you update regularly
```

from the above you are saying for every `array key` update our `this.data` which seems wrong, because the keys in an array is 0,1,2 which are the index.

> Both **for..of** and **for..in** statements iterate over lists; the values iterated on are different though, for..in returns a list of keys on the object being iterated, whereas for..of returns a list of values of the numeric properties of the object being iterated. [readmore](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)

So instead of the long trip your subscription code that handles the processing of the retrieved data should look like the one below

```
for (let story of data) { // now of
       // this.data = data; not needed else your data is always overriden
       // for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) { no need for this again since the above for..of is handling it
          this.hitsArray.push(story);
          this.data.hits.push(story);// add the new stories(as last element) to the main data array using this.data here now

          console.log(this.hitsArray);
      //  } for loop of this.data.length
      }
```

So with the above code following the comments should explain what the code is doing and how the irrelevant parts are causing data override.

**P.S.** your `this.data.hits` must be an **array** initialized as `[]` when the program is loading the component. And your `data` from your observable must be an **array** or if object with **hits** as **array** then use this code instead `for (let story in data.hits) {`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, ill do some testing with your recommendations! Ill get back to you. Cheers.

Comment: Hey Theophilus, sorry it took so long for me to get back to you, but i've been traveling, so i haven't worked on this webapp since we spoke. I've now tried out several possibilities, but it seems that the for..of loop through my array of objects perfectly, but it somehow makes my HTML (ngFor="let story of data.hits">) not working.

Comment: Ok i actually got it working by also changing the ngIf in the HTML (see OP post edit). New issue: the code pushes both old feed hits into the new array, upon changing feeds. How to make sure, that the feed is only pushed to the array, if the data comes from the same feed, without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

So this is the final fix (note: the hitsArray is being loaded as an empty array, every time the params changes):

Component:

```
this.storiesService.getData(this.page, this.hits, this.feed)
  .subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (!data || data.hits == 0) {
      this.finished = true;
      console.log("No more hits :-(")
    } else {
      this.finished = false;
      for (let story of data.hits) {
        this.hitsArray.push(story);
        console.log("Hit me!")
        console.log(this.hitsArray);
      }
    }
  })
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let story of hitsArray">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'image'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" />
    <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'video'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" width="150" height="94" />
    <div class="caption">
      <p>{{story.storyCity}}, {{story.storyCountry}}</p>
      <h3>{{story.storyHeadline}}</h3>
      <p>Uploadet {{story.uploadDate}}</p>
      <p>Bruger: {{story.userDisplayName}}</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Like</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks to @Theophilus for the suggestion! His example may work in most situations other than mine!